# I can't run jcontrol on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation

```
$ jcontrol 
usage: jcontrol host [portnum (def=10500)]
on terminal :apt-get install julius
```

I do not know where the problem lies

Comment: I have no idea what `jcontrol` is, but the "usage: jcontrol host [portnum .." tells you  a 'host' is a mandatory parameter.  The "portnum..." parameters are in [square] brackets thus are shown as optional (command will work with or without them). So at minimum specify a required host in your `jcontrol`  command

Answer (score 1):

```
   jcontrol is a simple console program to control julius running on other
       host via network API. It can send command to Julius, and receive
       messages from Julius.

       When invoked, jcontrol tries to connect to Julius running in "module
       mode" on specified hostname. After connection established, jcontrol
       waits for user commands from standard input.

       When user types a command to jcontrol, it will be interpreted and cor-
       responding API command will be sent to Julius. When a message is
       received from Julius, its content will be output to standard output.
```

For the details about the API, [see the related documents.](http://www.jcontrol.org/documentation/index_en.html)

The hostname is a required parameter and as your output specifies, the default port number is 10500.

```
OPTIONS

        hostname
          Host name where Julius is runnning in module mode.

        portnum
          port number (default: 10500)
```

It's also clear the julius must be installed and running in module mode on the host specified on the command line.

Sources:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/jcontrol.1.html

http://www.jcontrol.org/documentation/index_en.html